# HTTP response code said error, Callback API ВК

Tags: vkontakte-api

Решил заняться написанием ботов. Есть бот на PHP и на C# ASP.NET Core.

PHP:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_REQUEST)) {
    return;
}

$confirmation_token = '...';

$token = '...';

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

switch ($data->type) {
    case 'confirmation':
        echo $confirmation_token;
        break;

    case 'message_new':
        echo ('ok');
        break;
}
```

Этот код работает хорошо, ошибок никаких нет.

ASP.NET Core C#, класс контроллера:

```
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;

        public CallbackController(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Get([FromBody] Updates upd)
        {
            switch (upd.Type)
            {
                case "confirmation":
                    return Ok(_config["Config:Confirmation"]);
                default:
                    return Ok();
            }

            //return Ok();
        }
```

ASP.NET Core C#, класс Updates:

```
        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("object")]
        public JObject Object { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("group_id")]
        public long GroupId { get; set; }
```

Этот код работает хорошо только при "confirmation", при "message_new" выдаёт ошибку "HTTP response code said error".
Как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Короче - ответ прост. При отправке POST-запроса программа не может переобразовать JSON-файл в Updates, а сама проблема заключается в поле типа JObject. Что бы этого не произошло, нужно написать вот такой код:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Get([FromBody] object upd)
{
   JObject obj = JObject.Parse(upd);

   return Ok();
}
```